# Calculating the volume of a paraboloidal region

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an inequality that defines a paraboloid. I would like to calculate the volume of the intersection of this paraboloid and a cylinder of radius `R`.

```
ff[a_, d_, x_, y_, z_] := 
  16 a^2 y^4 + a y^3 (-32 a^2 - 8 d^2 - 8 x^2 - 8 z^2) + 
  a y (32 a^2 d^2 + 8 d^4 - 8 a^2 x^2 + 2 d^2 x^2 - 10 x^4 - 
  8 a^2 z^2 + 2 d^2 z^2 - 20 x^2 z^2 - 10 z^4) + 
  y^2 (16 a^4 - 8 a^2 d^2 + d^4 + 32 a^2 x^2 - 2 d^2 x^2 + x^4 + 
  32 a^2 z^2 - 2 d^2 z^2 + 2 x^2 z^2 + z^4) - (16 a^4 d^2 + 
  8 a^2 d^4 + d^6 + 20 a^2 d^2 x^2 - 3 d^4 x^2 - a^2 x^4 + 
  3 d^2 x^4 - x^6 + 20 a^2 d^2 z^2 - 3 d^4 z^2 - 2 a^2 x^2 z^2 + 
  6 d^2 x^2 z^2 - 3 x^4 z^2 - a^2 z^4 + 3 d^2 z^4 - 3 x^2 z^4 - z^6);

Vol[R_, a_] := 
  Integrate[
    Boole[ff[a, d, x, y, z] <= 0 && x^2 + z^2 <= R^2], 
    {x, -R, R}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -R, R}];
```

My problem is that Mathematica does not yield a result. Is there any way to do it?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ff[a_, d_, x_, y_, z_] := 
  16 a^2 y^4 + a y^3 (-32 a^2 - 8 d^2 - 8 x^2 - 8 z^2) + 
   a y (32 a^2 d^2 + 8 d^4 - 8 a^2 x^2 + 2 d^2 x^2 - 10 x^4 - 
      8 a^2 z^2 + 2 d^2 z^2 - 20 x^2 z^2 - 10 z^4) + 
   y^2 (16 a^4 - 8 a^2 d^2 + d^4 + 32 a^2 x^2 - 2 d^2 x^2 + x^4 + 
      32 a^2 z^2 - 2 d^2 z^2 + 2 x^2 z^2 + z^4) - (16 a^4 d^2 + 
     8 a^2 d^4 + d^6 + 20 a^2 d^2 x^2 - 3 d^4 x^2 - a^2 x^4 + 
     3 d^2 x^4 - x^6 + 20 a^2 d^2 z^2 - 3 d^4 z^2 - 2 a^2 x^2 z^2 + 
     6 d^2 x^2 z^2 - 3 x^4 z^2 - a^2 z^4 + 3 d^2 z^4 - 3 x^2 z^4 - 
     z^6);

Vol[R_?Positive, a_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Boole[ff[a, d, x, y, z] <= 0 && x^2 + z^2 <= R^2], {x, -R, 
    R}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -R, R}];

Vol[10, 1, 1]

(* 1599.87 *)

reg[R_?Positive, a_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ] :=
 ImplicitRegion[
  ff[a, d, x, y, z] <= 0 && 
   x^2 + z^2 <= R^2 && -R <= x <= R && -20 <= y <= 20 && -R <= z <= 
    R, {x, y, z}]

Volume[reg[10, 1, 1]]

(* 1599.87 *)
```

Comment: thanks, but Is it possible to find an analytical expression?

Comment: Without using numeric values, determining when `ff[a, d, x, y, z] <= 0` would seem unlikely.

Comment: @F.Mark perhaps you could either use this numerical procedure and plot some dependencies? Or you could try to nondimensionalize your function to use less variables?